# Select2 remote source on dropdown field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, inline-editing

I have a city field, where on inlinedit call it will load ajax data on dropdown list. Please check my code & let me know where am I wrong. I read the [select2 documentation](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        $('#city_id').editable({
            type: 'select2',
            name: 'otmp_tx_user_details:city_id',
            pk:"userdetailid:<?php if($student_info->userdetailid) echo $student_info->userdetailid; else echo "0";?>",
            ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo site_url()?>students/get_city_by_country", 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function () {
                    return;
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {results: data};
                }
            },
            url: "<?php echo site_url();?>students/inlineedit",
            success: function(data) {
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Here is my ajax data from PHP file:

```
$array = array(
               array("id"=>1,text=>"Dhaka"), 
               array("id"=>2,text=>"Pabna")
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Please help me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping your Ajax object inside a `select2` object, like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#city_id').editable({
        type: 'select2',
        name: 'otmp_tx_user_details:city_id',
        pk:"userdetailid:<?php if($student_info->userdetailid) echo $student_info->userdetailid; else echo "0";?>",
        select2: {
            ajax: {
                url: "<?php echo site_url()?>students/get_city_by_country", 
                dataType: 'json',
                data: function () {
                    return;
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    return {results: data};
                }
            }
        },
        url: "<?php echo site_url();?>students/inlineedit",
        success: function(data) {
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its work now. However when I typing a term it does not work auto select the result. For example, I typeing "bang" then it should show the auto select result with "bangladesh", now it only shows the underline with the result i.e on "bangladesh" it just show a underline on bang word. I am trying to improve my code with the following data function.                 data: function (term, page) {
                                                return {
                                                    term: term };
                                            },

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. Unfortunately I can't help you on your other issue, I can't see what is going wrong. Are you able to put together a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the issue? As a side note, I'd suggest raising this issue as a new question, as it is unrelated to your initial question.